# Can´t deploy to firebase cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

When I try to run an firebase deploy --only functions I get this error for ALMOST every function:

> "WARNING: Failed to delete temporary cache image to stable name; this will not affect current build: DELETE https://***********/gcf-artifacts/application--on_application_write/cache/manifests/4500b6e2-9253-4d70-8c91-5ba800c62978: DENIED: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.deleteArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/******_*_/repositories/gcf-artifacts" (or it may not exist)""

Can someone tell me what to do? Which account does not have the permission? Is it my admin-sdk service account?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to grant your account the "artifactregistry.repositories.deleteArtifacts" permission on the "gcf-artifacts" repository. This can typically be done using the Cloud Console or the gcloud command-line tool. For example, you can use the following gcloud command to grant the necessary permissions to the service account associated with your Firebase project:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT_ID> \
    --member serviceAccount:<SERVICE_ACCOUNT> \
    --role roles/artifactregistry.repositorie.deleteArtifacts
```

Replace <PROJECT_ID> with the ID of your Firebase project, and <SERVICE_ACCOUNT> with the email address of the service account that you are using to deploy your functions.

Comment: hey! thank you for your fast reply. But the command fails: 
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Role roles/artifactregistry.repositories.deleteArtifacts is not supported for this resource.